# Class is not a constructor, multiple 'require'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with class 'State', it has a model and controller file. However, when importing these classes on my main (app.js), there seem to be a clash as 'state.model.js' is 'required' both in app.js and state.controller.js. Thus, giving me the error, State is not a constructor.

app.js:

```
const State = require('./model/state.model');
const stateController = require('./controller/state.controller');

stateController.insert(msg, State.STATE_REMINDER.name, State.STATE_REMINDER.key.day, selected_day, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("[STATE][INSERT]", doc);
        });
```

state.controller.js:

```
const Database = require('../database');
const State = require('../model/state.model');
const db = Database.collection('states');

db.loadDatabase((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("[STATES] Database connected");
});

exports.insert = (msg, state, key, value, callback) => { // msg refers to Telegram Callback
    let insertState = new State(undefined, msg.from.id, msg.chat.id, state, key, value);
    console.log(insertState);
    db.insert(insertState, (err, newDoc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(err, newDoc);
    });

};
```

state.model.js:

```
const stateController = require('../controller/state.controller');

const STATE_REMINDER = {
    name: "STATE_REMINDER",
    key: {
        day: "DAY",
        time: "TIME"
    }
};

class State {
    constructor(id, user_id, chat_id, state, key, value) {
        this._id = id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.chat_id = chat_id;
        this.state = state;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

    static get STATE_REMINDER() {
        return STATE_REMINDER;
    }
}

module.exports = State;
```

This problem is actually fixed when i swap the order of codes in app.js to:

```
const stateController = require('./controller/state.controller');
const State = require('./model/state.model');
```

Why is that so? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a circular dependency loop:

app.js requires state.model.js which requires state.controller.js which requires state.model.js which requires state.controller.js etc etc

In this case, require will detect a circular dependency and will NOT go on forever. However this means at some point it will just return "null" instead of the actual class. It probably will look like this:

app.js -> requires state.model.js

state.model.js -> requires state.controller.js

state.controller.js -> requires state.model.js. At this point node detects the circular looop and will return null for state.model.js, then will begin to unwind the stack.

I'm not sure why it would work when you switch the order, the loop is still there and should be causing an issue still, probably some oddity in how node is importing the files.

Comment: Ah thanks! I guessed that it was circular dependency while browsing through other similar issues, however, just couldn't get why the order would've made it work. Will mark yours as accepted answer!

Comment: Yeah I dunno why order would make it work either... If you ever find out, please let me know, I'm curious.